# Objects are missing in WADL

Tags: rest, jersey, wadl

I have a web application using Jersey, and I would like to describe its' REST API with WADL.
Jersey generates .wadl file by default, but it does not contain objects (some of my REST calls send/return objects). Actually, I get something like this:

```
<method id="save" name="POST">
<request>
<representation mediaType="application/json"/>
</request>
<response>
<representation mediaType="application/json"/>
</response>
</method>
```

How can I create .wadl that describes also objects?

Answer (score 2):

Acceptable and returned types are described by XML Schema only when you are accepting/returning application/xml type. There is no generally accepted description of JSON types or structures, so WADL generated from Jersey doesn't contain related description (simply because there is no standard way how to achieve that).